# how can I clean route parameters previously passed from child screen in my case

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am developing a react-native project. Here is my main screen which can receive route parameters from child screen.
(User can navigate from `MainScreen` to `ChildScreen` and vise versa.)

```
const MainScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {

  if (route?.params) {
    //do something
  } else {
    //do something else
  }
 ...
}
```

When navigating back from child screen to main screen, inside `ChildScreen`, I have:

```
//this is inside Child screen
onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate("MainScreen", {data: 'foo'})
          }
```

Above code snippet is a illustration of how I pass route parameter from child screen to main screen.

Overall, it works well. However there is one issue. That's inside the `MainScreen`, once navigating back from `ChildScreen` to `MainScreen`, the value of the parameter inside `route?.params` is preserved. I mean if I kill the app's process and launch the app again which shows `MainScreen` again, the

```
if (route?.params) {
    //do something
  }
```

is executed because the `route?.params` contains the previously passed parameters from child screen. That is bad since I expect a clean start for my main screen. How to get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try `navigation.push` instead  of `navigation.navigate`.